# Cross-platform UI toolkit

Tags: user-interface, cross-platform

I need to write cross-platform GUI application, what toolkit can I use?
Currently I am working in Windows, MSVC, and Linux, gcc.

Comment: @animuson: Are you serious? This question was asked 3 years ago, and now you want to close it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most popular options are [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/) and [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwindows.org/).  I, personally, have found Qt much more feature-rich.

A newer option, however, (depending on what you are developing) is Silverlight/Moonlight.  Flash can also work for cross platform GUI development, in some cases.

Comment: ...and, of course, there is also venerable GTK. :)

Comment: Forgot to mention, that I need free toolkit. wxWidgets is free, and Qt is not, is this correct?

Comment: No - Qt is free, too.  It's now LGPL, so can be used freely in commercial software, too.

Comment: @Vlad: I didn't mention GTK, although it's an option, too.  Last time I used it, it was very "odd" on Windows, since it's been added much later.  I know some very successful software uses it, but I tend to not consider it for Windows dev. (yet)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [**QT**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_%28framework%29).

Answer (score 0):

If you want something simpler to learn and use, you might consider Real Studio.  With Real Studio, you can easily create cross-platform software for Windows, OS X, Linux and the web using an easy-to-use IDE and a Basic-like, object-oriented programming language.

http://www.realsoftware.com