# SWT-like GUI toolkit for C or C++

Tags: c++, c, user-interface, cross-platform, swt

Do you know any cross-platform GUI toolkit like swt for C (using default widgets in each operating system = right pics on [eclipse.org/swt](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/)) ? There is an implementation of swt for D language called DWT but I need it for C or C++. Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351987/cross-platform-ui-toolkit ?

Comment: Not exact duplicate, asking for equivalence of Java SWT GUI for C or C++.

Comment: There is http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/iup/ too

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com) ([community](http://qt-project.org/))
2. [wxWidgets](http://wxwidgets.org)
3. [FLTK](http://www.fltk.org/)
4. [GTK+](http://www.gtk.org)
5. [FOX](http://www.fox-toolkit.org/)
6. [Notus](http://notus.sourceforge.net/)
7. [VCF](http://vcf-online.org/) - **EDIT2** seems to be inactive for a few years

You can read some details in [that wiki](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/WxWidgets_Compared_To_Other_Toolkits).
First 4 are pretty popular, the rest I dont know.

**EDIT:**
8. [There is C++ port](http://pure-native.com/swtcpp/index.html) but it seem Windows only for now
9. [SWT/Fox - C++ port on top of FOX toolkit](http://swtfox.sourceforge.net/) - seems to be dead for more then 3 years
10. Also you can try .NET + Mono. But not for commercial project, I think

Qt, FLTK and GTK+ use their own widgets system, i.e. they replace native windows, buttons, etc. Whereas wxWidgets provides a layer on top of native system. Hence:

- with wxWidgets you get 100% native look&feel on every platform without any effort.
  CON - you get native bugs too :). Different behaviour could be undesirable
- At least Qt can emulate native look&feel (some people say it is not perfect on MacOS X). Also KDE is written in Qt, so for KDE desktops Qt is native

**EDIT2:**
Just found this *really* extensive [list of widget toolkits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_widget_toolkits) on wikipedia

Answer (score 0):

The qt framework provides crossplatform functionality:
http://qt.nokia.com/products

Answer (score 0):

Take a look of [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/).